# apt-pin locally built packages

Tags: linux, debian, apt, apt-get, dpkg

I have patched and recompiled a debian package. By default when I upgrade, apt wants to upgrade it with the SAME version from the repository instead.

Now, I want to convince it (by using apt-pinning, and not hold) to keep the local package if the version is the same, and try to upgrade only if the remote version is newer.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Just make a local revision and upgrade the version, something like:

```
dch -v 1.0-1local1
```

Then pin that version.

Comment: I know that, which is what I wanted to avoid

Comment: @LtWorf: why? You are modifying the package. A new version just reflects that.